# Match identical words in two prints

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using os to list the filenames within a directory. I am also using pandas to list the contents of one column in a CSV file. I have printed the results of both and now I want to match the names that appear in both prints and also identify which names are exclusive to one print. Below is my code which gets the names and the contents of the CSV file.

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd


path = "/mydir/csvfile"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

for file in dirs:
    print file

fields = ['Column']

df = pd.read_csv('/mydir/csv_file', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)

print df.Column
```

*** EDIT ***

I have come up with this solution that works.

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd


path = "/mdir/csvfile"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

list_1 = [file for file in dirs]



fields = ['column']

df =     pd.read_csv('/mydir/csvfile', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)

list_2 = df.column.values.tolist()

list_3=[]


for i in list_1:
    if i in list_2:
        list_3.append(i + " True") 
    else:
        list_3.append(i + " False") 

print list_3
```

Comment: Realised I forgot to really include a question. How would I go about doing this, is there a way to compare and match both prints?

Comment: dont print, save those values to variables and compare those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
for file in dirs:
    print file
```

Build a list:

```
files = [file for file in dirs]
```

Then use the DataFrame to check:

```
df.Column.isin(files)  # this will check elementwise
Out: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: Column, dtype: bool
```

Or

```
df.Column.isin(files).all()  # if all of them are the same
Out: True
```

Comment: You are welcome. Note that this can miss if `files` have extra files. You can do the comparison other way around: `pd.Series(files).isin(df.Column)` to make sure.

Comment: Do you know how I could get this to work to still give the element along with true or false? e.g     0 12fhaj True, 1 757dyah False, 2 fhjf8282 True...

Comment: You can assign it to the current DataFrame: `df['check'] = df.Column.isin(files)`. When you print the DataFrame you'll see the corresponding result next to each file.

Comment: I came up with another way which I will post in my question, I used your solution to come up with this, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand it you have two lists. One from the directory and another from a column in Pandas. You want the elements that are in both lists as well as the elements that are unique to each list. Lets say your lists are like this:

```
List1 = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd', 'e', 'f']
List2 = ['c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' , 'i']
```

Then your code to produce what I think you want could use list comprehensions and go like this:

```
overlap = [i for i in List1 if i in List2]
nonOverlapList1 = [j for j in List1 if j not in overlap]
nonOverlapList2 = [k for k in List2 if k not in overlap]
```